# Code will not check more than one duplicate integer in a one-dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays

I compiled a code to check for duplicates in a one dimensional array, the only issue I am having is that it will display one duplicate, but not the others. I have included my code. I am a novice, and I struggled to get this far.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void duplicate(int array[], int num)
{
    int *count = (int *)calloc(sizeof(int), (num - 2));
    int i;

    printf(" The duplicate integers in this array are: ");
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (count[array[i]] == 1)

            printf(" %d ", array[i]);

        else

            count[array[i]]++;

    }
}

int main()
{
    int array[] = {7, 77, 42, 2, 1, 4, 2, 7, 42};
    int array_freq = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

    duplicate(array, array_freq);

    getchar();


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are *way* out of bounds in the  `count` array, doing `count[array[i]]` will mean that you use e,g, `array[1]` as an index in the `count` array, and `array[1]` is `77` which means you are using `77` as an index into `count` which have only 7 entries.

This will of course lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @PatrickTrombley the array would need to have `INT_MAX` elements (if all values are positive), but if you used a bit array that would need "only" `1 + INT_MAX / 8` bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the problem that you have about accessing `count` out of bounds, as pointed out by @JoachimPileborg in his answer, I think you don't have the right logic to check for duplicates.

Let's start with the first element of `array`, `7`.

Check whether `7` is found later. When found, print the duplicates.

Then note somewhere that you have already checked for duplicates of `7`. When you encounter `7` while iterating over `array`, you don't have to check for duplicates of `7` again.

```
void duplicate(int array[], int num)
{
   int i;
   int j;
   int* status = calloc(sizeof(int), num);

   printf(" The duplicate integers in this array are: ");
   for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
   {
      if ( status[i] == 1 )
      {
         // Already visited and marked as duplicate
         // Go on to the next item.
         continue;
      }

      for ( j = i+1; j < num; ++j )
      {
         if (array[i] == array[j])
         {
            // Note that array[j] has already been visited and
            // marked as a duplicate.
            status[j] = 1;

            // If array[i] is not already printed, print it and
            // mark it as a duplicate.
            if ( status[i] == 0 )
            {
               printf(" %d ", array[i]);
               status[i] = 1;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   printf("\n");

   // Make sure to deallocate the memory before returning from
   // the function.
   free(status);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I see where I went wrong. As I examine this code closely, I now see that it is eerily similar to a code I had to write in Java about three months ago. Thank you again.